# How to extract data from a LogLogPlot?

Tags: plotting, data

Can I get data from `LogLogPlot`?
I try cases and it doesn't work. Any idea?
I would like to have a list of all points in this curve

```
LogLogPlot[fvv[nu, 0.01, 1.9890000000000002`*^39, 9.454140999315537`*^22],   
    {nu, 10^11, 10^17}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

Comment: `LogLogPlot[
 fvv[nu, 0.01, 1.9890000000000002*^39, 9.454140999315537*^22], {nu, 
  10^11, 10^17}, PlotRange -> Full] //Normal //Cases[#,Line[___],{1,Infinity}]& //First` ?

Comment: andre, works same like I did, but I get number which I dont know what it is :)

Comment: We have no idea what you are getting, until we know what `fvv` is?

Comment: Maybe : `LogLogPlot[nu,   
    {nu, 10^11, 10^17}, PlotRange -> Full] //Normal //Cases[#,Line[___],{1,Infinity}]& //First //First //Exp`?

Comment: @andre With any level spec where you want `{1, Infinity}`, it is simpler to write just `-1` which is equivalent to `{1, -1}` where `-1` is the lowest depth of the expression. And, yes it took me longer to realize that than I care to admit. :)

Comment: @JESUS_M `Plot` and its kin (all the log plots) use `GraphicsComplex` as it simplifies things. That is why `Normal` is needed, it expands the `GraphicsComplex`.

Comment: Yes @andre it is this what i need, can I also get y as Second or which command I should to use. In this case I got only x bu I need y too.

Comment: Indeed working I change function.
Thanks @andre

Comment: I propose to close the question